# App Debug is not working in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have set `APP_DEBUG=true` in `.env` file, and also configure the `app.php` in `config` folder `debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true)`. But the page is not showing the debugging or errors.

If I try a page which is not in the views just showing **"Sorry the page is not found"**, and there are two files. named `.env` and `.env.example`

Comment: please post some more data here, like routes, controller functions etc

Comment: Do you have `"filp/whoops": "~2.0"`?

Comment: Tried `php artisan config:clear`? and if running on php artisan serve tried restarting the serve command?

Answer (score 4):

This may be due to cache. Try this command

> php artisan config:cache

Answer (score 0):

As @abhishek mentioned in a comment, you should make sure that you clear your cache. First check to see if your still in production mode by entering  `php artisan env` it should still come up as `Current application environment: production` Then enter `php artisan config:cache` . If your `'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'local')` and `'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true),` are set you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command

`Artisan::call('cache:clear');`

`Artisan::call('config:clear');`

`Artisan::call('config:cache');`

`Artisan::call('view:clear');`

Answer (score -2):

Open inspector in your browser and look at network for status code from page you are trying to visit. I am pretty sure it's a 404 not found. (so it's not found, not an 500 error).

If you want to customize your 404 view you can do so by creating `404.blade.php` file in your `resources/views/errors/` folder

[image: 404]

Comment: Here the question is why is he not able to see the debug screen. He has not asked how to change the 404 file.